# Spark get rows between 2 specific rows

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:
[image]

I want to get rows with values between ('2/1/2020' and '2/5/2020')
[image]

I tried:

```
df.select([c for c in df.columns if c > '2/1/2020' & c < '2/5/2020']).show()
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Because the header is csv type(Date)
Thanks !

Comment: Instead of using '&' try using 'and'. & is a bitwise operator which is not really helpful with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`&` use **`and`**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) boolean operator.

```
df.select([c for c in df.columns if c > '2/1/2020' and c < '2/5/2020']).show()
```

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4,5,6)],['pro','2/1/2020','2/2/2020','2/3/2020','2/4/2020','2/5/2020'])

df.select([c for c in df.columns if c  > '2/1/2020' and c < '2/5/2020']).show()
#+--------+--------+--------+
#|2/2/2020|2/3/2020|2/4/2020|
#+--------+--------+--------+
#|       3|       4|       5|
#+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Short question, do you know how to take first 2 rows also [PROVINCE_STATE] and [COUNTRY_REGION)

Comment: I mean in the same select, to take [PROVINCE_STATE] and [COUNTRY_REGION] and c  > '2/1/2020' and c < '2/5/2020'

Comment: Try with `df.select([c for c in df.columns if (c  > '2/1/2020' and c < '2/5/2020') or (c.upper() in ['PROVINCE_STATE','COUNTRY_REGION'])]).show()`